# Alter data attribute using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, touch

I would like to change a data attribute on touchscreen devices using javascript or jquery. The text which says 'scroll down for more information' should say 'touch the arrow' on touchscreen devices. The touchscreen-browser detection works, I just cannot change the data-info attribute.

Here is my attempt at this:

HTML

```
<button class="trigger" id="trigger" data-info='Scroll down for more information'><span>Trigger</span></button>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
<script>
if ('ontouchstart' in window) 
{

  // 'Getting' data-attributes using getAttribute
  var trigger = document.getElementById('trigger');
  var touchText = trigger.getAttribute('data-info'); 

  // 'Setting' data-attributes using setAttribute
  trigger.setAttribute('data-info','Touch the arrow'); 

}
</script>
```

CSS (if that matters at all)

```
button.trigger::before {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 100%;
    left: -100%;
    padding: 0.8em;
    width: 300%;
    color: #fff;
    content: attr(data-info);
    font-size: 0.35em;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

Thank you so much for your help!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code updating the attribute as shown is correct ([example](http://jsbin.com/mixir/1)). If it's not working the most likely explanation is that your `script` element is **before** your `button` element in the markup. In that case, the button won't exist as of when the code runs, and so the element won't be updated. Make sure the script is *after* the `button` in the markup.

Comment: That was the solution!! Without you, I would have never figured this out! Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 1):

Your code should be working, via `setAttribute`, however In Javascript, you may also use [HTMLElement.dataset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.dataset) if you'd like:

```
var trigger = document.getElementById('trigger');
trigger.dataset.info = "Scroll down for more information";
```

As per what T.J. Crowder states, your issue could relate to the position of your script, relative to your "trigger". Either move your script to the end of your `body`, or use some sort of `onload` event (however, moving your scripts to the end of your body is the preferred method by many):

```
window.onload = function() {
    // your code here
}
```

Comment: While true on the browsers that support it, as the OP's code is correct, it's not really useful to just point them at another way to do the same thing.

Comment: It's always useful to at least be aware of alternatives, but I did append a short blip about how OP's code should work just fine.

Comment: It's not useful for *answering this question*.